# can't override cart page created by default on woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, child-theming

I'm attempting to edit the cart page in WooCommerce. I copied the content of cart.php from the core plugin and pasted it into a file named cart.php in a folder named woocommerce/cart, located within my child theme directory. I made a few changes to see if they would appear, but the page is still blank. What might I be missing?

Thank you.

Comment: The file you modified is the template for displaying the cart in the frontend. _"I would like to edit this page and others that are in my admin dashboard."_ - that however sounds like you wanted to modify something in the admin dashboard? Please clarify.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I want to override pages created within my dashboard with custom ones, allowing me to personalize them using code, as the current pages do not offer the flexibility to customize the blocks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the cart block on your cart page while customizing and overriding the classic cart template. If you want to use your customized cart template, you'll need to replace the cart block with the cart shortcode.

```
[woocommerce_cart]
```

- https://woo.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

Comment: It's not what I want. I would like to edit cart with cart.php and checkout with form-checkout to add/remove custom blocks (my blocks). However, it doesn't work for me because my pages in the admin board override it. If I remove them, I get a 404 error. Is there anyone who understands my issue?

Comment: If you want to override the cart or checkout block, you need to work on a different file. But the PHP file you are overriding will work only for the classic (shortcode) cart and checkout page template. By the way, for a clear visual explanation, you can use https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/ or https://www.loom.com/.

Comment: Follow this guide if you're looking to customize the cart and checkout block: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce-blocks/docs/designers/theming/cart-and-checkout.md

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the guide shared uses CSS, which isn't what I'm seeking. I want full control over the layout using HTML and PHP. For example, to customize the shop page, I've created archive-product.php and content-product.php to display images with the same structure as my portfolio. I'm aiming for similar customization for the cart and checkout pages, but I'm yet to find the best way to override them solely with code.

Comment: I've figured out that it was again a caching issue. Even after clearing the cache, nothing happened until I tried changing the theme and then switched back to mine. After doing so, the changes appeared, very frustrating.